# Seleccionar automaticamente un tab predeterminado android

Tags: android

Resulta que en mi app tengo 4 tabs, de los cuales uno de ellos es el perfil de la persona. Me gustaria que cuando el usuario abra el activity que contiene estos 4 tabs, se redireccione solo al tab del perfil y no que me abra automaticamente el primer tab ( de izquierda a derecha ) ¿Es posible ? espero haber sido claro. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo solucioné, hay que agregar lo siguiente, en donde *número de tab* es el número de índice que comienza desde *0*:

```
tabhost.setcurrentTab(número del tab);
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes especificar que [clase de tabs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) estas usando, pueden ser de un tabhost o de un actionbar tab, para definir el tab default en un **[tabhost](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html)** se usa el metodo [setCurrentTab()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html)

```
myTab.setCurrenTab(n);
```

Recuerda que el indice inicia desde 0.

Para obtener cual es el tab default lo puedes obtener mediante getCurrentTab()